# DC buck Convertor

Tags: arduino

I want to power SIM800L which requires around 4v and 2amps(at peak only). If I attach DC buck converter to Arduino Uno 3.3V output, and power SIM800L, is it safe?

Comment: A buck converter can't convert 3.3V to 4V.

Comment: No it doesn't. It specifically says input voltage must be higher than output voltage.

Comment: @Justme Got it Sir! Thanks. I didn't read that carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buck converters step down voltage.

Boost converters step up voltage.

The 3.3V of an arduino is limited by the arduinos regulator and is unlikely to support 4v * 2A or 8W stepped up, which would likely be 3.3V 2.4 Amps plus the efficiency penalty of the regulator (say 20% so 3.3V * 3A). It will burn out. Those on board arduino regulators are only good up to 1 amp in best conditions.

Comment: Ok I got the difference between buck and boost converters.

Comment: If I use 20V 2 Amp power supply, get two buck convertors, Power one arduino and other powers sim800l? Will it be OK?

Comment: Yeah that should

Comment: @ Passerby In this case, don't the Power supply unit eliminate the need for capacitors?

Comment: Notreally. The buck converters will need some and you probably need some for the sim radio as 2 amps at peak is needed very fast and the caps help smooth out the power draw.

Comment: @Passserby But the buck converter which I bought has its own 2 capacitors. Do I need to add more?

Comment: Reality is that I have never used a capacitor and do not know even a single thing about them.